# How to save an ArrayList of Objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I am creating a project where I have a user enter a Book title and I put that into an ArrayList which is later cast into a RecyclerView. How could I store this ArrayList so that the data is not lost when the app is destroyed. Below is what I am currently on. I have tried alternatives such as TinyDB but with no success. (By the way, the 2nd parameter is a check box)

```
var todoList = arrayListOf<Todo>(
        Todo("Write your first TODO statement", false)
    )
   
    val adapter = TodoAdapter(todoList)
    binding.rvTodos.adapter = adapter
    binding.rvTodos.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    binding.btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
        val title = binding.etTodo.text.toString()
        val todo = Todo(title, false)
        todoList.add(todo)
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(todoList.size - 1)
    }
```

Comment: simple use shared prefrence , realm , room data base to store the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store your data using a database like SQLite, Room Database or Firebase.
where in your case I see that a database like Room would be the best choice to store the Array list data.

you can start reading about Room database by following codelab provided by Android Developers through this [link(kotlin)](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin)  or follow their text tutorial through this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

afterwards when you get back to your application after being destroyed you could just fetch the data from the database using one line select query and load it again into your recycler view adapter.

Comment: I would want the user to access the data offline, which is why I wouldn't want a database. Is there any other way to store data offline?

Comment: Room database works offline as it's normal use, it's not an online database by natural and as far as I know you can't make it an online one.